# Opening up TCP Sockets in Java EE Webapplication

Tags: c++, architecture, jakarta-ee, jms

We have to communicate with a C++ component from a Java EE web application and my proposal involved using JMS server to communicate with the C++ component which is located on other machine.

However the developer of the C++ component wants me to open up TCP/IP sockets from the webapplication and communicate over XML. My view is that socket programming in web application is error prone and will not scale well since there is a limited amount of sockets that can be opened up.

Please let me have your architecture/design preference on using JMS vs TCP/IP sockets.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's case by case. But give HTTP a serious chance. It is a good way to cross platform boundaries. It gives you ways to swap out the backend easily and there are many ways to scale it. I've used it from various platforms to hit centralized authentication service written in modern language. I've also done the opposite by putting frontend to a legacy code by turning it into a web server.

The best part about HTTP is that it's a standard protocol, so almost any platform is able to serve it and consume it out of the box. HTTP(S) or TCP takes care of many of the issues like reliability and security.